# How to loop recursive and map first time all possible levels to recursive?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, recursion

```
public void IterateOverChild(Transform original, int currentLevel, int maxLevel)
    {
        if (currentLevel > maxLevel) return;
        for (var i = 0; i < original.childCount; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log($"{original.GetChild(i)}");
            allChildren.Add(original.GetChild(i));
            IterateOverChild(original.GetChild(i), currentLevel + 1, maxLevel);
        }
    }
```

Usage example

```
void Start()
{
  IterateOverChild(transform, 0, 23);
}
```

but in this case i'm guessing that there are 23 levels to loop through recursive.
maybe there are 60 levels or 3 levels ?

how can i make that firs time the method will loop through all sub objects and each time it's getting deeper to a new level to log for example the level number like :

```
Debug.Log("Level : " + levelNum);
```

And in the end also to use Debug.Log to display the total levels.
So in the end i will know from how much levels amount i can chose to recursive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class Recursive : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public int levelNum = 0;
        public int totalLevels = 0;
    
        void Start()
        {
            RecursiveMethod(transform);
            Debug.Log("Total Levels : " + totalLevels);
        }
    
        void RecursiveMethod(Transform obj)
        {
            levelNum++;
            Debug.Log("Level : " + levelNum);
            foreach (Transform child in obj)
            {
                RecursiveMethod(child);
            }
            totalLevels = levelNum;
            levelNum--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting wrong number of levels.  some levels in the debug.log are the same number like level 3 logged three times other levels twice the levels order is not from 1 to the last and in the end i see total levels 2 but there are much more then 2.

Comment: Change it to pass in a `int level` inital call passes 1 and the recursive call passes `level +1`